# Can I suppress the Apple Pay popup in my app?

Tags: ios, nfc, applepay

I have created an app with the [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) framework. My IOT device contains both Bluetooth and NFC. When I bring my Apple device in to NFC range, the Apple Pay popup triggers.

Is their any way to suppress the Apple Pay popup while my app is in the foreground or background?

Answer (score 15):

First, I would have thought that you would be able to make a Bluetooth connection without getting close enough for the NFC to be detected, but that isn't your question.

You can suppress the Apple Pay display *when your app is in the foreground* by calling [`requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression(responseHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation) from the PassKit framework.

Note that:

> This method requires a special entitlement issued by Apple. If the entitlement is not present, the request will fail with a PKPassLibrary result.

Specifically, you need the `com.apple.developer.passkit.pass-presentation-suppression` entitlement.

If this app is for your own use you should be able to just add this entitlement to your entitlements file.  To submit it to the App Store you will need to contact Apple to get this entitlement.

You cannot suppress Apple Pay when your app is not in the foreground.

Answer (score 4):

To suppress the presentation of the Apple Pay dialog when it detects a compatible reader, there is an entitlement required in order for the [requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression(responseHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation) method to function in the desired manner.

To request the special entitlement, email apple-pay-provisioning@apple.com. Be sure to include information about your company and describe the use case requiring suppression of the Apple Pay dialog. Once you have the entitlement, you can go ahead with using the [requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression(responseHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation) method.